# Program in docker container will only write to volume when run from interactive session

Tags: docker

I have a docker image which contains a C++ executable. The executable analyzes some files, and outputs results to a .txt file. To make this easy to use, I use a volume to pass in the images and receive the output, e.g. `docker run -t -v /input/files/dir:/app/input myimage myexecutable --input-dir /app/input`. By default the program writes the output .txt file to the same directory as the input files.

The program (not written by me) prints an error that the output .txt file cannot be opened. I thought this was a volume permissions issue or selinux issue, but when I run the same image with an interactive session: `docker run -t -v /input/files/dir:/app/input myimage bash` and run `myexecutable --input-dir /app/input` from in the running container, everything works fine and the output .txt file is written to the volume as expected.

From a source search, it looks like the C++ program runs `fp = fopen(txt_fn, "w+");`, and if `if(fp!=NULL)` it writes the file, otherwise the error is printed.

Why would the file pointer open only work when running from an interactive session in the docker container?

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was probably just an issue of using an old version of Docker, specifically version 17.03.1-ce, as the error does not reproduce on an up to date version. Sigh.